# Do not trigger div click event if a link inside of it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that expands when clicked. I also have a link inside this div. Expected behavior is for the click event to be ignored when the link is clicked, but obviously clicking anywhere in the div will trigger the event. I've tried stopPropagation(), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#infobox').on('click', expandFunction);

$('#infobox a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

<div class="infobox">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working, but "infobox" is a class and not an ID. Try `$('.infobox')`. See [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). Also, in this case, `stopPropagation()` should be sufficient. `stopImmediatePropagation()` also prevents "any additional handlers on an element from being executed", which doesn't seem necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function expandFunction() {
    alert("expanded")
}


document.getElementById("infobox").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName != event.currentTarget.tagName) return;
    expandFunction();
});

document.querySelector("#infobox a").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  
      alert("linkclicked")
})
```

```css
div{
padding:15px;
background-color:gray;
}

a{
padding:15px;
background-color:silver;
color:white;
margin:5px;
display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="infobox" class="infobox">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

first you must set Id for infobox

```
<div id="infobox" class="infobox">
```

you can use this code to prevent click from other elements

```
$('#infobox').on('click', function(event){ 
if(event.target.id!= event.currentTarget.id) return;
expandFunction();
});
```